# Apache - Access files from multiple different folders

Tags: apache, web, permissions

Is there anyway to have a bunch of iframes on one html page that link to several different text files located elsewhere on the server?

For example, if my apache server hosts its HTML pages in:
`C:\Apache\WebDocs`,
Is there anyway to link several different log files from different locations like" `C:\game1\logs\log.txt` and `C:\GameServer\logs\console.txt` all into one webpage using iframes?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create shortcuts to your current apache document root and give apache user read permission to the original file. Personally, I haven't tested this on a windows machine. Otherwise, you can use Alias directive.

```
Alias /log1 C:\game1\logs\
```

and you can call the url as `http://localhost/log1/`
That should help as well.